why can't i install requirements.txt in ubuntu
I used AWS EC2 to deploy the fastapi application to the server.
And to run the server, I first ran pip install -r requirements.txt in the terminal, but an error occurred.
I'm using MAC
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-70:~/fastapi-castone$ pip install -r requirements.txt

I ran it like this
output
Collecting mysqlclient==2.2.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 100))
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 90.4/90.4 kB 10.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qf5kyjk/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qf5kyjk/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-5qf5kyjk/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 155, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 49, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 28, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I am now following the video from this YouTube link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgSnz7kW-Ko

You have to install pkg-config in Ubuntu first:
sudo apt-get install pkg-config

The log said pkg-config not found.
